# Convert symbolic expressions to Python functions using SymPy

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, symbolic-math, solver

I have a rather large symbolic function that is evaluated for different values of a parameter in a loop. In each iteration, after finding the expression of the function, partial derivatives are derived. Something like this:

```
from sympy import diff, symbols,exp

def lagrange_eqs(a):
    x,y,z= symbols('x y z')
    FUNC=x**2-2*x*y**2+z+a*exp(z)
    d_lgrng_1=diff(FUNC,x)
    d_lgrng_2=diff(FUNC,y)
    d_lgrng_3=diff(FUNC,z)
    return [d_lgrng_1,d_lgrng_2,d_lgrng_3]
```

Next, I need to convert the output of this function to a Python function so that I can use `fsolve` to find x, y, z values for which derivatives are zero. The function must take x,y,z as a list.

Now here is my problem: how do I convert the output of the above function to a Python function which could be passed on to a solver. Such a function should look like this (for a=3):

```
def lagrange_eqs_solve(X): 
    x,y,z=X
    return [2*x - 2*y**2, -4*x*y, 3*exp(z) + 1]
```

I simply copied the output of the first function to build the second one. Is there a way I could code it? (Matlab has a built-in function for this, called matlabFunction)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want [`lambdify`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/utilities/lambdify.html).

```
f = lambdify(((x, y, z),), lagrange_eqs(a))
```

will give you a Python function `f` that you can evaluate like `f((1, 2, 3))` (for `x=1`, `y=2`, `z=3`). I have made the arguments in a tuple so that it will work with scipy's `fsolve`.

You can set the `modules` flag to lambdify to determine where the `exp` function will come from. For instance, to use `numpy`, use `lambdify((x, y, z), lagrange_eqs(a), modules="numpy")`. To use the standard library math library, use `modules="math"`. By default, numpy is used if it is installed, otherwise math is used.

Comment: Also, if multiple values of `a` are used, you would probably want to make that an argument to the lambdified function as well, so that you only have to create it once.

Comment: Thanks @asmeurer. `lambdify` does convert the output to a function, but it cannot be passed on to `fsolve`, because we need a function with one argument (a list of variables). When I try `fsolve(f,(0,0,0))` or `fsolve(f,[0,0,0])`, it throws `TypeError: <lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: '_Dummy_17' and '_Dummy_18''`.

Comment: Use `lambdify(((x, y, z),), lagrange_eqs(a))`.

Comment: in the answer, please add the missing comma in `f = lambdify(((x, y, z),), lagrange_eqs(a))`. I am not able to edit it.