# Python Updating Source Code wrt Output of a Function

Tags: python, input, output, equation

As example, my first module is

```
from sympy import *
x,y=symbols('x y')

def A():
    equation=2*x+y
    return equation

print(A())
```

the output is

```
2*x + y
```

my second module is

```
def B(x,y):
    equation=2*x + y
    return equation
```

I have to copy past the output of first module to second one each time from the terminal. Is there a way to pass this output automatically to the source code of B(x,y)?

Thank you for your attention

Comment: Have you consider merging the modules together? or importing the first module into the second, calling the first module in the second module and just passing the value in the same script?

Comment: I will give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: I tried it, but it outputs the same symbolic value. The type of the output is <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>

Comment: Can you give us your input, and desired output?

Comment: B(2,1) should output 5. With copy paste from terminal, it can succeed.
I recently found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34195502/convert-symbolic-expressions-to-python-functions-using-sympy
Maybe it could help

Comment: lamdify is the solution for my problem(above link). Thank you for your time.